# ConcurrentDictionary thread safe and efficient change of a property witihin a dictionary value

Tags: c#

There are quite a few posts about thread-safe changes to a ConcurrentDictionary, however, all of the examples I have searched concern themselves with changing the whole value. I think this is a slightly different question..

I'm after some guidance on the best way to change a property of an object value already in a ConcurrentDictionary?

For example, I could do the following but not sure if it's thread-safe

```
CustomObject obj;
if (customObjectDictionary.TryGetValue(objectKeyToChangeProperty, out obj))
{
    obj.Property2 = "NewData";
}
```

Another way is to copy the dictionary using ToArray and then get the required object, amend the property and then use the thread-safe AddOrUpdate method

```
obj = customObjectDictionary.ToArray().Select(x => x.Value).FirstOrDefault();
if(obj != null)
{
   obj.Property2 = "NewData";
   customObjectDictionary.AddOrUpdate(obj.Key, obj, (oldkey, oldvalue) => obj);
}
```

This seems a bit of a long winded way of doing this and not sure if calling ToArray will be performant if doing this many times.

Sample Code is below:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private ConcurrentDictionary<int, CustomObject> customObjectDictionary { get; set; }
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        InitialzeObjects();
        Start();
    }

    private void InitialzeObjects()
    {
        customObjectDictionary = new ConcurrentDictionary<int, CustomObject>();

        var o1 = new CustomObject() { Key = 1, Property1 = 1, Property2 = "Object1" };
        customObjectDictionary.AddOrUpdate(o1.Key, o1, (oldkey, oldvalue) => o1);

        var o2 = new CustomObject() { Key = 2, Property1 = 2, Property2 = "Object2" };
        customObjectDictionary.AddOrUpdate(o2.Key, o2, (oldkey, oldvalue) => o2);
    }

    private async void Start()
    {
        bool complete = await Task.Run(() => Test());
    }

    private async Task<bool> Test()
    {

        int objectKeyToChangeProperty = 2;
        CustomObject obj;

        // Method 1 change local variable directly
        if (customObjectDictionary.TryGetValue(objectKeyToChangeProperty, out obj))
        {
            obj.Property2 = "NewData";
        }

        // Method 2 - make copy first then 
        obj = customObjectDictionary.ToArray().Select(x => x.Value).FirstOrDefault();
        if(obj != null)
        {
            obj.Property2 = "NewData";
            customObjectDictionary.AddOrUpdate(obj.Key, obj, (oldkey, oldvalue) => obj);
        }

        return true;

    }
}

public class CustomObject
{
    public int Key { get; set; }
    public int Property1 { get; set; }
    public string Property2 { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A *concurrent collection* is *thread safe* in the respects that it will always be *internally consistent*, even if it's at the cost of you getting *snapshots* of the collection (among other trickery). However, and it's a big however, the objects inside the collection or the code you write that use it are not guaranteed to be *thread safe*.

I'm not sure of the actual problem you are trying to solve or the threading nature of properties you are trying to change. Though, the safest bet (and if you are unsure) is to just use a `lock` when accessing these *properties*.

Answer (score -1):

It is not safe, so you must protect it somewhere else.

There are multiple patterns and that will depend on the current scenario. 
For example, if you need to increment a variable:

```
    if (customObjectDictionary.TryGetValue(objectKeyToChangeProperty, out obj))
    {
        obj.Property1++;
    }
```

behind the scene you are reading Property1, adding 1, and save it again in one line, but not in an atomic instruction, in the middle it could have change 50 times.

you can protect thta code with a lock, inside the if, but another developer can come 2 years later and do the same somewhere else, and not realize that he/she is forgetting the lock

Then you could enforce the read and write inside the object that locks, foe example:

public class CustomObject
   {
    private int _Property1;

```
public Property1 
{
  get 
  {
     return _Property1;
  }

  public void IncrementProperty1By (int increment) 
  { 
    lock { ... Property1++ ... }
  }
```

}

Comment: To whoever marked this with -1, I would appreciate a comment on why so i can learn as well! Thanks!